# How do I reliably expose aggregated CSS/JS to a third party app?

Tags: 7, css-js-aggregation

(TL;DR at the bottom)

For the purposes of "theming" some other internal apps based on ASP etc., I need to make a D7 site's CSS/JS available at a permanent, reliable URL; one which will also self-update. That is, when CSS/JS changes, the file will be updated to reflect that.

To this end, my intention was to generate these files myself using a module. I only really need to replicate the header/footer of a particular content type. I figured I'd accept an argument of "content type" and generate the files based on a random node's css/js, or maybe there's a way to use a "blank" node, I don't know. I just need to provide back a stable aggregated file for each of css and js. It could live in either the theme or files directory I guess.

I'll probably need to write a "rebuild" hook to update the files too but that could just be a cron task or maybe run on cache clear.

TL;DR - how do I programmatically create an aggregated css/js file given a content type, and store this?

Comment: Interesting question. When you say the CSS/JS for a content type, does this actually vary? Usually it won't - rather the HTML will vary and the CSS/JS will be the same.

Comment: It will actually vary depending on the html as well, which is now making this even more difficult (or even impossible). I wanted to be able to reflect any design changes made via a "reputable source" of css/js in the third party apps so that the header and footer just stay sane.

Comment: Can you use the [Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation module](https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg) to do the aggregation. You could then implement its `hook_advagg_changed_files()` to get the paths to aggregated css and js files whenever they are changed. I'm not sure if you can have it create aggregated files for just a certain content type, or perhaps it's sufficient for your purposes if every content type uses the same aggregated files.

Comment: The paths need to remain constant, which is why I think I need to create a copy of the files and a callback to reference/provide them. I haven't seen anything in the advagg api that suggests I can plagiarise from there, but I will check out the module's generic setup anyway. I still believe that I will require a callback to provide these though.

Comment: My mistake, `hook_advagg_changed_files()` has the css and js files that were changed, not the aggregated files. It may still be useful for you to know which files have changed. It may be possible to hook into the AdvAgg module another way to get the list of aggregated files that you can then copy and rename to do what you want. `hook_advagg_build_aggregate_plans_post_alter(&$plans, $type)` looks like a good candidate, but I'm not certain. There may also be a way to get the aggregated files from the database and/or through Drupal cache.